# Multi word filter in Elasticsearch 2

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query (filter) that is working fine against Elasticsearch 1.5:

```
...
"terms": {
   "jobTitle": ["big", "data"],
   "execution": "and"
}
```

That will find records that have both "big" and "data". `execution` is deprecated in 2.x though and I can't find any documentation about how I would write that query in a way that would work both against 1.x and 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bool query, this is the same of terms query do in background

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "match": {
                      "jobTitle": "big"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "match": {
                      "jobTitle": "data"
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Will be like this example :D